# List of most common network vulnerabilities a la OWASP Top 10

Tags: network, known-vulnerabilities

I am trying to find the most commonly used attack vectors/techniques on computer networks in the style of the owasp top 10, for my thesis work. The reports shouldn't be older than 2-3 years. Can you provide some sources?

[Edit:] Edited the title to the suggestion of @schroeder
Also, I have found a possible solution, but it isn't a precompiled list. There is a list called [CWE](http://cwe.mitre.org/index.html) where one can find common weakness types like [this one](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/287.html)

Since CVEs are mapped to these categories, one can use the [NVD statistics engine](https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/statistics) to manually request statistics and compile this kind of ranking.

The existing CWE/SANS Top 25 mentioned in an answer below is very old

Comment: Suggested edit to the title: "List of most common network vulnerabilities a la OWASP Top 10"

Answer (score 5):

The WA in OWASP stands for Web Application, so OWASP doesn't produce one.

Other organizations may have this information. You might want to look at the SANS list at http://www.sans.org/top25-software-errors/.

Comment: the OP did mention "in the style of OWASP"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that there are some sources focusing only on network security in this case, since OWASP itself focusing only on web apps security.

But mostly, people will look into [CVE](https://cve.mitre.org/) to find out latest or recorded vulnerabilities. You can search through CVE list to find out anything you need for your thesis.